# Chrome Extension - CSS messes up on certain pages

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome Extension that inserts a DIV on top of an existing page. I have given my DIV the distinct ID name, 'juxiSidebar'. In addition, all of the ID and Classes I insert into the page contain the prefix 'juxi'. The problem is that when I visit certain pages, sometimes my CSS formatting gets messed up, and I am unsure why this is happening. When I search the page for any IDs/Classes that start with 'juxi', I just see my own tags.

Here is a snippet of how I am inserting my nodes:

```
var sidebar = document.createElement('div');
sidebar.id = "juxiSidebar"; 
document.body.appendChild(sidebar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only ID and class selectors can affect the style of your element, but also other selectors, such as `div`, `body > div`, etc.

Make sure that **all** relevant styles for your element are set.

Comment: Sounds good. Is there a certain way prevent my code from inheriting the CSS from the page?

Comment: @user1277607 No, you have to define each individual property. Check the defeault values on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_Reference

Comment: @SimpleCoder In Chrome extensions, IFrames are not an easy option: The `window` object of the page *and* IFrame cannot be accessed directly within the content script.

Comment: @RobW: Thanks for setting me straight; I did not know that.